# Firebase JWT-php 'Signature verification failed' on JWT::decode

Tags: php, jwt

Here's my code generating the token:

```php
public static function GenerateNewAuthTokens(User $user): string {
    $issuedAt   = new DateTimeImmutable();
    $expire     = $issuedAt->modify('+' . AuthenticationHelper::AUTH_EXPIRE_MINUTES . ' minutes');
    $username   = $user->Username;
    $issuedAtTimestamp = $issuedAt->getTimestamp();

    $auth_data = [
        'iat'  => $issuedAtTimestamp,                // Issued at: time when the token was generated
        'iss'  => AuthenticationHelper::SERVER_NAME, // Issuer
        'nbf'  => $issuedAtTimestamp,                // Not before
        'exp'  => $expire->getTimestamp(),                           // Expire
        'userName' => $username,                     // User name
    ];

    return JWT::encode(
        $auth_data,
        AuthenticationHelper::SECRET_KEY,
        AuthenticationHelper::ALGORITHM
    );
}
```

Here is my code attempting to decode the token:

```php
public static function GetAuthData(): ?object {
    $headers = getallheaders();
    if (isset($headers) && count($headers) && isset($headers['Authorization']) && strlen($headers['Authorization']) > 7) {
        try {
            $token = explode(" ", $headers['Authorization'])[1];
            $decodedToken = JWT::decode($token, new Key(AuthenticationHelper::SECRET_KEY, AuthenticationHelper::ALGORITHM));
            return $decodedToken;
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            //TODO
            $err = $th;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It throws the "Signature verification failed" error in the JWT code [here](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/92aa12d73dfbf4ee157cf4d01c5342869dcd9d56/src/JWT.php#L130).

So far as I can tell - I'm following the example given on the [repo home screen](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) to a reasonable approximation.

I am using `HS512` but have tried `HS256` as well with no difference.

I have confirmed that the token I'm attempting to decode is exactly what was generated in the first method.

It's failing the compare check [here](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/92aa12d73dfbf4ee157cf4d01c5342869dcd9d56/src/JWT.php#L312), due to `$hash` and `$signature` not matching.

Comment: `$hash` looks like: `� ����?͚�ZM�[MQP\4��0�*$��1�o�i�v-#��ҭ��cY%Ȇ���Vh�\(�%�`

Comment: I have same problem with the latest lumen and firebase jwt for RS256. Because I have run the same key on my older lumen and firebase jwt it works perfectly fine was thinking my keys are wrong but I think is some error at the same place as you pointed

Comment: Note, I also opened a ticket on the GitHub repo, will update here if anything comes of that.

Comment: thank you I hope some one will help to fix the bug

Comment: @user8012596 I might try dropping the version a couple numbers too and see if that fixes my issue. I also haven't tried encoding and decoding immediately afterwards to see if that's fine. I'll try to do that as well.

Comment: @user8012596 Found my problem - see my answer - I'm dumb

Comment: in my case I have checked I am not trimming any token. I send the exact thing because the exact setup work on an older version without issue

Comment: If you encode the token, and immediately decode it. Does it work?

Comment: no I have confirmed and test it does not work. I have checked nothing wrong on the token

Comment: @user8012596 can you make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) or something with your test code? Wonder if there's something simple, but not obvious.

Comment: the problem I am using the same codes and I copy and paste my older version it works perfectly fine. Only when I start using a new application is the issue ? Maybe I can post my middleware codes

Comment: This would be helpful. Hopefully there's something I can suggest once you provide that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out I wasn't sending the exact same token back that I was receiving. When JWT encodes the token data, it trims off the `=` at the end of any of the base64 encoded strings.
What I had stored contains those `=` at the end (usually). Because of this, when it ran its compare - it failed.

In summary - dur - check the values better.